# How do I target a button to get text from a specific textarea, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created multiple `<div>` elements with jQuery, each with a `<span>`, `<textarea>` and a button. I'm not sure if this is even doable, but how could I trigger the button to alert the value of the textarea next to it? Eventually I'm going to try to save that value in local storage and save it if the page is refreshed.

I've attempted `$this`, `before()`.

Thanks for any help, sorry for my not so good post (it's my first one).

**jQuery:**

```
var scheduleHours = [
    "8am", "9am", "10am", "11am", "12am", "1pm", "2pm",
    "3pm", "4pm"
] 

for(i = 0; i < scheduleHours.length; i++) {
    $('.container').append('<div class="row" ><span>'+scheduleHours[i]+'</span></div>')
    
}

// $('.row').append('<span></span>');
$('span').addClass('col-2 time-block hour')  
$('.row').append('<textarea></textarea>')   
$('textarea').addClass('col-8')
$('textarea').attr({
    name: 'agenda',
    id: 'agenda ',
    rows: '2',
    cols: '100%',
    placeholder: 'Please insert your plans here'
})
$('<button></button>').appendTo('.row').addClass('col-2 saveBtn');
$('button').text('Click here to save');
```

Comment: `alert($('#agenda').val())`?

Comment: Returns undefined

Comment: Check `$('#agenda').length` to see if that `textarea` has been attached to the DOM.

Comment: If you are this new to web development why are you learning jQuery? jQuery is an outdated method and if you are investing your time to learn how to build web apps you would be much better investing that time into a modern library like Angular, Vue or React. The only reason to learn jQuery these days is if you have taken a job supporting a legacy app.

Comment: if your button is right after the text area, then try `$(this).prev()`

Comment: alert($('#agenda').length) tried this and returns 0

Comment: Thanks Alwaysa it worked out I guess I was using it wrong beforehand